# Async testing scenario fails when call made to command interface

Tags: c#, asynchronous, testing, xamarin, icommand

I have a problem with testing an `ICommand` scenario in a Xamarin project. I have extracted the logic into a demonstration below.

Scenario N1 runs smoothly however I need Scenario N2 to work. The problem with scenario N2 is that as soon as it gets to the

```
await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(1000));
```

it jumps back to the test method `Assert` where obviously the `SetSurveyContext(int x)` is not executed yet.

The strangest thing is that if I run this code from the Xamarin framework inside the app everything works fine probably because I am executing the Command in a wrong manner.

Really stuck with this question, I have tried numerous ways to run the command but neither have worked. Please help if someone has come across the same problem. Thanks.

**Scenario 1** - working

```
[Test]
public async Task NewSurvey_SendObjectWithOnlyDate_StaticSurveyResourceIdAndDateSet()
{
        var mvmTest = new TesterPage();
        await mvmTest.NewSurvey();
        Assert.That(mvmTest.setter, Is.EqualTo(3));
}

public partial class TesterPage : ContentPage
{
    public int setter = 0;

    public TesterPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    public async Task NewSurvey()
    {
        await PostNewSurvey();
    }

    private async Task PostNewSurvey()
    {
        var response = await Another();
        SetSurveyContext(response);
    }

    private async Task<int> Another()
    {
       await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(1000));
       return 3;
    }

    private void SetSurveyContext(int x)
    {
        setter = x;
    }
}
```

Test green, everything runs smoothly.

**Scenario N2** - fails

```
[Test]
public async Task NewSurvey_SendObjectWithOnlyDate_StaticSurveyResourceIdAndDateSet()
{
        var mvmTest = new TesterPage();
        mvmTest.NewSurveyCommand.Execute(null);
        Assert.That(mvmTest.setter, Is.EqualTo(3));
}

public partial class TesterPage : ContentPage
{
    public int setter = 0;

    public TesterPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        NewSurveyCommand = new Command(async () => await NewSurvey());
    }

    public ICommand NewSurveyCommand { get; private set; }

    public async Task NewSurvey()
    {
        await PostNewSurvey();
    }

    private async Task PostNewSurvey()
    {
        var response = await Another();
        SetSurveyContext(response);
    }

    private async Task<int> Another()
    {
       await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(1000));
       return 3;
    }

    private void SetSurveyContext(int x)
    {
        setter = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see what your question is. Could you post your `TesterPage.NewSurveryCommand.Execute()` calling method in your Xamarin project?

Comment: If you look inside the Tester Page constructor you can see NewSurveyCommand = new Command(async () => await NewSurvey()); which as far as I understand means that await NewSurvey() method will be executed if we call NewSurveyCommand.Execute(null); from elsewhere ( from the test in our case). Does that answer your comment?

Comment: My question is, in scenario 2 we have a problem because the control is returned to the test before the methods are finished that set the value that we are checking for in the tests.

Comment: The Execute method itslef is under the hood in Xamarin framework but there is info on what they have implied here https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Command/

Comment: How do you see it's working in your Xamarin application?

Comment: Since this is a case extract, in my Xamarin app its a bit more sophisticated but it fails the same way, however when the Execute method is called within the framework, ie when I run the app in the simulator everything is fine, the logic finishes up correctly.

Comment: So thats why I think I should call the command from the test the way it is called by the framework and then it should work I guess.

Comment: What about creating a private field in TesterPage that contains your Task and can be waited for in your test via Reflection?

Comment: Good idea, gonna try that.

Comment: Can u suggest a code snippet for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162162/discussion-between-user78403-and-yuri-zolotarev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I have solved this problem with @YuriZolotarev in chat, here the solution we found for everyone else who encounters it:
**The problem:**
When `Task.Run()` is called in `TesterPage.Another()` the main thread jumps back to the test method. There it executes `Assert.That()` immediately, even before `SetSurveyContext` has set `setter` to`3`.
**The solution:**
We found the solution to create a new private field in `TesterPage` which should contain the `Task` started in `TesterPage.Another()`. This `Task` can be waited for in the test method via Reflection. Everything could look like this:

```cs
[Test]
public async Task NewSurvey_SendObjectWithOnlyDate_StaticSurveyResourceIdAndDateSet()
{
    var mvmTest = new TesterPage();
    mvmTest.NewSurveyCommand.Execute(null);
    // Use Reflection to wait for the task
    (GetInstanceField(typeof(TesterPage), mvmTest, "runningTask") as Task).Wait();
    Assert.That(mvmTest.setter, Is.EqualTo(3));
}

// A helper method to simplify Reflection
internal static object GetInstanceField(Type type, object instance, string fieldName)
{
    BindingFlags bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic
    | BindingFlags.Static;
    FieldInfo field = type.GetField(fieldName, bindFlags);
    return field.GetValue(instance);
}

public partial class TesterPage : ContentPage
{
    public int setter = 0;
    private Task runningTask; // The field our Task object is saved in

    public TesterPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        NewSurveyCommand = new Command(async () => await (runningTask = NewSurvey()));
    }

    public ICommand NewSurveyCommand { get; private set; }

    public async Task NewSurvey()
    {
        await PostNewSurvey();
    }

    private async Task PostNewSurvey()
    {
        var response = await Another();
        SetSurveyContext(response);
    }

    private async Task<int> Another()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(1000));
        return 3;
    }

    private void SetSurveyContext(int x)
    {
        setter = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Coolest hack!!! At the point when the command is executed in the constructor of TesterPage we set our private field runningTask to the method NewSurvey. We intercept the Task field in the test to wait for its completion. I am trying to implement this but can't figure out a syntax error at  NewSurveyCommand = new Command(async () => (runningTask = await NewSurvey())); The runningTask doesn't want to get assigned to await for NewSurvey saying "only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new obj expression can be used as statement. Any ideas? @user78403  Thanks!

Comment: My mistake. Put `await` before the bracket in front of `runningTask =`. I'll correct it in the answer.